# Вывод треугольника определенной формы в два цикла for

Tags: c

Помогите пожалуйста вывести на экран треугольник изображенный на рисунке ниже не более чем в два цикла `for` и без помощи дополнительных переменных. При вводе нечетного числа должен получится верхний вариант, соответственно, введя четное число - нижний.

---

### [image: Примеры вывода фигуры]

У меня, к сожалению, при помощи доп. переменной получился корректный вывод только первой фигуры, вторая отображается неправильно, потому что исчезает единица при делении на два, если переменная `size` нечетная.

```
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::cin;
using std::endl;

void main()
{

int size, k = 0;

cin >> size; cout << endl;

  for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
  {
      for (int j = 0; j <= k; j++)
      {
          if (k >= j) cout << "*";
      }

      if (i < (size / 2)) k++; else k--;
      cout << endl;
  }

}
```

В общем, нужна ваша помощь хотя бы в избавлении от лишней переменной ;(

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Так сойдет?

```
int main()
{
    int size;
    cin >> size;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
    {
        for(int j = (size-1)/2 - abs((size-1-2*i)/2); j >= 0; cout << '*', j--);
        cout << endl;
    }
}
```

Без `abs`:

```
int main()
{
    for(int size, i = (cin>>size, size); i >= 0; cout << endl, --i)
        for(int j = (size-1-2*i < 0) ? size-1-i:i; j >= 0; cout << '*', --j);
}
```

Голый C:

```
int main()
{
    for(int size, i = (scanf("%d",&size),size); i >= 0; puts(""), --i)
        for(int j = (size-1-2*i < 0) ? size-1-i:i; j >= 0; putchar('*'), --j);
}
```

Comment: а можно как-то без `abs()` обойтись?

Comment: Можно - см. дополненный ответ.

Comment: Здорово! Пожалуйста объясните только `i = (cin>>size, size)` и почему в основном цикле операция предекремента, а не пост- `(--i)`?

Comment: Ну поставьте пост, в данном случае это не имеет значения. Дело привычки, скорее. Хотя для пользовательских типов могут быть отличия. `i = (cin>>size, size)` - оператор запятой, позволяющий объединять инструкции в одну. Сначала считывается `size` из `cin`, затем, после запятой - возвращаемое значение, которым и инициализируется переменная `i`.

Comment: Понял, спасибо ;)

Answer (score 1):

Что-то у вас всё как-то очень сложно. Делайте проще:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <string>
```

```
int size = 6;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    std::cout << std::string(std::min(i, size + 1 - i), '*') << std::endl;
}
```

Пояснение: если брать `nstars = i`, получится треугольник с острым концом вверх. А если брать `nstars = size + 1 - i`, получится треугольник с острым концом вниз (попробуйте!). А минимум даёт как раз пересечение.

---

Для C получается немного многословнее:

```
int size = 5;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; i++)
{
    for (int j = 0; j < i && j < size + 1 - i; j++) printf("*");
    printf("\n");
}
```

---

Вот вам для прикола с одним циклом и без библиотек:

```
int size = 5;
int nstars = 1;
for (int i = 1; i <= size; /* nothing*/)
{
    printf("*");
    nstars--;
    if (nstars == 0)
    {
        printf("\n");
        i++;
        nstars = size + 1 - i;
        if (nstars > i)
            nstars = i;
    }
}
```

Comment: нужно только с библиотекой <iostream>, другие запрещают :(

Comment: @Strngr: А что, и `std::string` запрещают? o_O Вы ж указали язык C++, а не C.

Comment: простите, я изменил метку на С

Comment: @Strngr: Окей, обновил ответ.

Comment: @Strngr: Вот вам варианты без дополнительных переменных

Answer (score 0):

Вот, пожалуйста.

```
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    while (true)
    {
        const char c = '*';

        std::cout << "Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): ";

        unsigned int n;

        if (not (std::cin >> n) or (n == 0)) break;

        std::cout << '\n';

        for (unsigned int i = 0; i++ < n; )
        {
            unsigned int m = (n + 1) / 2 < i ? n - i + 1 : i;
            for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++) std::cout << c << "  ";
            std::cout << '\n';
        }

        std::cout << std::endl;
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Вывод программы на консоль может выглядеть следующим образом:

```
Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 10

*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 9

*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 8

*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 7

*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *  *  *
*  *  *
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 6

*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *  *
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 5

*
*  *
*  *  *
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 4

*
*  *
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 3

*
*  *
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 2

*
*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 1

*

Enter a non-negative number (0 - exit): 0
```

Либо вы можете сделать более плотный вывод заменив в данном предложении вывод двух пробелов

```
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++) std::cout << c << "  ";
                                                       ^^^^
```

на один пробел

```
for (unsigned int j = 0; j < m; j++) std::cout << c << ' ';
                                                       ^^^^
```

Comment: только с `<iostream>` пожалуйста

Comment: @Strngr Без проблем.:)